# My LogIn page has 2 different types of users , each in a separated collection in the firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

am using a userId , that must exist in one of these 2 collections "Users" OR "StoreOwners"

one of them has a document inside the collection , and the other will cause an error since the document doesn't exists in the collection ... how to fix this problem ?

```
  CheckInWhichDocument() {
    String userId = _auth.currentUser!.uid;

    FirebaseFirestore.instance. 
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
    print("you entered users collection");
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('StoreOwners')
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
    print("you entered storeOwners collection");
    });
  }
```

the error "Null check operator used on a null value"
this error is caused by one of the collections because the document doesn't exist

(the userId exists in one of the collections)

Comment: This error means that the _auth.currentUser is `null` at the point where you runned that code, while you used `!` to say that it isn't

Comment: `doc(/*...*/).get()` will always return a `DocumentSnapshot` object even if the document do not exist in your DB.